# NgRx Properties of Object in store is always undefined?

Tags: angular, undefined, ngrx, ngrx-store

I'm currently using NgRx 8 to store images with imagename and url:

```
export default class AzureImage {
    Id: number;
    Name: string;
    Url: string;
  }
```

I have a list of all Images in my Homecomponent, if i click on one Image, a new component is loaded with ImageDetails. In the URL i have the id of the image. Now i want to get the ImageName of the AzureImage-Object. So i call the store and get the AzureImage-Object with the is. When i print the Object to the console, i can see the Object with name and url.

But if i call Object.Name afterwards the Name is always undefined.

Here is the Component-Class:

```
export class AzureimagedetailsComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private aspNetApiService: AspNetApiService, private store: Store<{ azureImages: AzureImageState }>) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    let id = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');

    this.store.pipe(select('azureImages'))
      .pipe(
        map(store => {
          return store.AzureImages[id];
        })
      ).subscribe((k: AzureImage) => {
        console.log('Here i can see the Object with the Name',k)
        if (k !== null && k !== undefined) {
          console.log('Here is the name undefined',k.Name)
          this.aspNetApiService.analyzeImageByAzure(k.Name)
            .pipe(
              map(x => {
                console.log(x);
                this.analyzedImage = x;
              })
            )
        }
      });
      this.store.dispatch(AzureImageActions.BeginGetAzureImageAction());
  }
```

I'm new to NgRx for State Management. Am i midding something or is it normal that i can' access properties of objects?

Comment: This question looks unrelated to ngrx (in terms of the problem)... is it k.Name or k.name? Please include the output of `console.log('Here i can see the Object with the Name',k)`

Comment: Ok. i don't really get it. Because you wrote this i checked the console log. there it was 'name'. But i defined the AzureImage-object with 'Name'. I changed it to 'name' and now it works. I guess thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure your model matches what is returned from the backend OR map to the front end model

EITHER

```
export default class AzureImage {
    id: number; 
    name: string; // or whatever BE returns
    url: string;
  }
```

OR in API service

```
getAll(): Observable<AzureImage[]> {
    this.http.get(...).pipe(
        map(data => data.map(d => {
            return {
                    Id: d.id,
                    Name: d.name,
                    Url: d.url
            }
        })
    )
}
```